# want to create registration page using asp.net identity in ASP.NET webform application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Trying to create registration page provided by asp.net identity. I am getting the following error:
**System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: manager'**

Please help me to find out why it is showing null. Any help is highly appreciated.

My code for the register.aspx.cs is:

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
       var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
       var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = EmailId.Text };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

And I have not made any changes in this part. My **ApplicationUserManager** code looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dotn know exactly where you are going wrong. but this link is really useful in learning identity http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

Comment: check out part 2 as well

Comment: if you can place where you get error, its more helpful to provide solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are missing this line

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

in your `Startup.Auth.cs` file.

As in this bit:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create); // <-- this is missing
        // etc...
```

Comment: where shall i place this code. app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);  Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: do you have `Auth.Starup.cs` file?